# Group together arbitrary date objects that are within a time range of each other

Tags: python, date, sorting, group-by, intervals

I want to split the calendar into two-week intervals starting at `2008-May-5`, or any arbitrary starting point.

So I start with several date objects:

```
import datetime as DT

raw = ("2010-08-01",
       "2010-06-25",
       "2010-07-01",
       "2010-07-08")

transactions = [(DT.datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%d").date(),
                 "Some data here") for datestring in raw]
transactions.sort()
```

By manually analyzing the dates, I am quite able to figure out which dates fall within the same fortnight interval. I want to get grouping that's similar to this one:

```
# Fortnight interval 1
(datetime.date(2010, 6, 25), 'Some data here')
(datetime.date(2010, 7, 1), 'Some data here')
(datetime.date(2010, 7, 8), 'Some data here')

# Fortnight interval 2
(datetime.date(2010, 8, 1), 'Some data here')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import datetime as DT
import itertools

start_date=DT.date(2008,5,5)

def mkdate(datestring):
    return DT.datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

def fortnight(date):
    return (date-start_date).days //14

raw = ("2010-08-01",
       "2010-06-25",
       "2010-07-01",
       "2010-07-08")
transactions=[(date,"Some data") for date in map(mkdate,raw)]
transactions.sort(key=lambda (date,data):date)

for key,grp in itertools.groupby(transactions,key=lambda (date,data):fortnight(date)):
    print(key,list(grp))
```

yields

```
# (55, [(datetime.date(2010, 6, 25), 'Some data')])
# (56, [(datetime.date(2010, 7, 1), 'Some data'), (datetime.date(2010, 7, 8), 'Some data')])
# (58, [(datetime.date(2010, 8, 1), 'Some data')])
```

Note that 2010-6-25 is in the 55th fortnight from 2008-5-5, while 2010-7-1 is in the 56th. If you want them grouped together, simply change `start_date` (to something like 2008-5-16).

PS. The key tool used above is `itertools.groupby`, which is explained in detail [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Edit: The `lambda`s are simply a way to make ["anonymous" functions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda). (They are anonymous in the sense that they are not given names like functions defined by `def`). Anywhere you see a lambda, it is also possible to use a `def` to create an equivalent function. For example, you could do this:

```
import operator
transactions.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))

def transaction_fortnight(transaction):
    date,data=transaction
    return fortnight(date)

for key,grp in itertools.groupby(transactions,key=transaction_fortnight):
    print(key,list(grp))
```

Comment: `//14` is the same as `/14` in Python2, but is necessary in Python3 to get integer division (since `/14` gives floating-point division in Python3). By using `//14` you future-proof your code a little bit. See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: // is used as integer division but actually it is division by numbers with result automatically rounded down to nearest integer. When used with floats the result stays float.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how the `lambda` works here. As I understand about `lambdas`, they're particularly useful for making them work over `iterable`s. Do `sort()` and `groupby()` perform some iteration operations on their `key`s?

Comment: Thank you, @Tony. It's good to point out that `//` is *not* the same as `/` (in Python2) when operating on floats.

Comment: @Kit: In `groupby`, each element in `transactions` is handed to the `key` function. An element of `transactions` is a tuple `(date,data)`. The `key` function `lambda (date,data):fortnight(date)` receives `(date,data`) as input and returns `fortnight(date)`. This is just an integer used to classify which group `(date,data)` should be grouped with.

Comment: @Kit: `lambda`s are just a way to create functions. They don't necessarily have anything to do with iterables, but you are right, they show up a lot with `sort` and `groupby` because those functions take `key` arguments which expect functions. I could rewrite the above without any `lambda`s. I'll edit my post to show what I mean.

Comment: Please validate my understanding. In every iteration of `groupby`, `key` __sometimes__ receives a new integer value (or any type, integers at least in this example). Then every element of `transactions` that gets the same `key` gets grouped together. Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct Kit, @unutbu: // is not limited for Python3, it is same in Python2 also (actually I normally use Python 2.7 and tested it there). So yes it is not same as Python2 /, but same as Python2 //.

Comment: `groupy` iterates over the elements of `transactions`. Each element is passed to the function specified by the `key` argument. The `key` function does not receive an integer, it returns an integer. The consecutive elements that have the same integer are grouped together.

Comment: @Kit: You're very welcome. `itertools` is a great tool to have in your pocket, well worth every second spent studying it.

Answer (score 4):

Use itertools groupby with lambda function to divide by the length of period the distance from starting point.

```
>>> for i, group in groupby(range(30), lambda x: x // 7):
    print list(group)


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
[28, 29]
```

So with dates:

```
import itertools as it
start = DT.date(2008,5,5)
lenperiod = 14

for fnight,info in it.groupby(transactions,lambda data: (data[0]-start).days // lenperiod):
    print list(info)
```

You can use also weeknumbers from strftime, and lenperiod in number of weeks:

```
for fnight,info in it.groupby(transactions,lambda data: int (data[0].strftime('%W')) // lenperiod):
    print list(info)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [pandas `DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling) works too. Given OP's data, but change "some data here" to 'abcd'.

```
>>> import datetime as DT
>>> raw = ("2010-08-01",
...        "2010-06-25",
...        "2010-07-01",
...        "2010-07-08")
>>> transactions = [(DT.datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%d"), data) for
...                 datestring, data in zip(raw,'abcd')]
[(datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 1, 0, 0), 'a'),
 (datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 25, 0, 0), 'b'),
 (datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 1, 0, 0), 'c'),
 (datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 8, 0, 0), 'd')]
```

Now try using pandas. First create a `DataFrame`, naming the columns and setting the indices to the dates.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(transactions,
...                   columns=['date','data']).set_index('date')
           data
date
2010-08-01    a
2010-06-25    b
2010-07-01    c
2010-07-08    d
```

Now use the [Series Offset Aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) to every 2 weeks starting on Sundays and concatenate the results.

```
>>> fortnight = df.resample('2W-SUN').sum()
           data
date
2010-06-27    b
2010-07-11   cd
2010-07-25    0
2010-08-08    a
```

Now drill into the data as needed by weekstart

```
>>> fortnight.loc['2010-06-27']['data']
b
```

or index

```
>>> fortnight.iloc[0]['data']
b
```

or indices

```
>>> data = fortnight.iloc[:2]['data']
b
date
2010-06-27     b
2010-07-11    cd
Freq: 2W-SUN, Name: data, dtype: object
>>> data[0]
b
>>> data[1]
cd
```